# How can I click a button to launch an ItemSelected event of spinner control?

Tags: android

I have a spinner control with setOnItemSelectedListener in my app,  when I select an item of the spinner, the event onItemSelected will be launched.
Now I hope to click a button to launch the onItemSelected event, how can I do? Thanks!

```
spinnerFolder.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
                //Do Business Logic
            }           
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }   
        });
```

Comment: How would you know which item to target from spinner? Would it be the current selected item?

Comment: It's the current selected item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the following from your button listener:

```
spinnerFolder.getOnItemSelectedListener().onItemSelected(spinnerFolder, spinnerFolder.getSelectedView(), spinnerFolder.getSelectedItemPosition(), spinnderFolder.getSelectedItemId());
```

That's all :-)

Comment: Well, it's the shortest way to trigger the requested event. ;) This was the actual question here! If it makes sense to trigger one object's event by another object's event from an architectural point of view is of course another discussion.

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter (int arg2) of onItemSelected for your spinner is the position, so you can get the current selection by

```
String selection = (String) mSpinnerAdapter.getItem(position);
```

or use `mSpinner.getItemAtPosition(position)` if you don't have a custom adapter.

Store the current selection somewhere and pick it up in the onClickListener for your button.

Answer (score 0):

When you populate the spinner with some data, you will have some sort of list objects (Strings, custom object, whatever) in the `SpinnerAdapter`, you'll keep a reference to that list, let's call it: `private List<Object> dataList = ...`

First of all I would create a method that would handle the specific data object:
    protected void doBusinessLogic(Object myObj) {
       // do the things that make you happy
    }

Then call this from listener as:

```
spinnerFolder.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3)    {
                // args2 is the position from backed data list
                doBusinessLogic(dataList.get(args2));
            }           
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }   
        });
```

Then from button listener you would call above method again, but the object index you would get is from [`spinnerFolder.getSelectedItemPosition();`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItemPosition%28%29):

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int dataIndex = spinnerFolder.getSelectedItemPosition();
                doBusinessLogic(dataList.get(index));
            }
        });
```