# How to launch a click event of a button?

Tags: android

I hope to launch a click event of the button btnAdd if the app is run for the first time.

I have read [How can I click a button to launch an ItemSelected event of spinner control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17610578/how-can-i-click-a-button-to-launch-an-itemselected-event-of-spinner-control)

How can I do? Thanks!

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.unlock_main);

    IniControls();      

            if (IsFirstRun){
        Button btnAdd=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
                //launch a clike event of the button btnADD
            }   

}

 private void IniControls(){
         findViewById(R.id.btnAdd).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(getApplicationContext(),ui.UnlockAddWiFi.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_ADDWIFI);             
    }
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmm. Easiest way I can think of is to make a preference.

```
private Button btnAdd;

   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.unlock_main);
    IniControls();  
    SharedPreferences sp =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    final Boolean IsFirstRun =  sp.getBoolean("firsttime", true);
    sp.edit().putBoolean("firsttime", false).apply();
    if (IsFirstRun){
        btnAdd.performClick();
            }  
} 
 private void IniControls(){
    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(getApplicationContext(),ui.UnlockAddWiFi.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_ADDWIFI);             
    }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but after I launch  btnAdd click event for the first run, I still need launch  btnAdd click event in futurn.

Comment: I'll add the code in a couple hours, I'm on my phone. But what you want to do is create the button first then in the if statement do btnAdd.performClick(); . Your button also needs to have an OnClickListener if it doesn't already.

Comment: Code changed to suit your needs

Answer (score 0):

Just write a method that will act as the onClick() content and place it in the onClick() listener and in the SharedPreferences as Solamum has suggested.

```
private Button mButton = null;
.
.
.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.unlock_main);
    initControls();

    /****************************************************************/
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    final Boolean IsFirstRun =  sp.getBoolean("firsttime", true);
    sp.edit().putBoolean("firsttime", false).apply();
    if (IsFirstRun){
          myClickEventMethod();
    }         
}

private void myClickEventMethod(){
    Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(getApplicationContext(),ui.UnlockAddWiFi.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_ADDWIFI); 
}

private void initControls(){
     mButton = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            myClickEventMethod();
         }
     }); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your way is good, but I hope to use this way spinnerFolder.getOnItemSelectedListener().onItemSelected(spinnerFolder, spinnerFolder.getSelectedView .just like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17610578/how-can-i-click-a-button-to-launch-an-itemselected-event-of-spinner-control